# What the heck is a queue family?

Tags: c++, vulkan

Okay, so I have been working on a Vulkan project recently, and I have came across a "queue family". What is it?

I've tried looking up the value in windows debugger, but it is just a weird looking memory address.

pci is just an instance of VkDeviceCreateInfo.

```
pci.pQueueCreateInfos->queueFamilyIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

A queue family defines the properties of a number of queues supported by the hardware.

When you instantiate a physical device you can enumerate the queues it supports using `vkGetPhysicalDeviceQueueFamilyProperties` which returns a number of `VkQueueFamilyProperties`. You can then query the results to find the queue(s) that you require for your application, e.g. `VkQueueFlag.VK_QUEUE_GRAPHICS_BIT` for rendering. When creating the logical device you build a number of `VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo` for the queues that you require, each contains the appropriate queue family index.

More details:  [Vulkan tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Physical_devices_and_queue_families)

> Note that in your code `pQueueCreateInfos` should be pointing to the array of `VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo` and **not** the queue family index.

The value you looked at in the debugger is indeed just a memory address, i.e. an 'opaque' handle. Just about every Vulkan 'object' is a handle.